# Bad access error on CFSetRemoveValue(RACActiveSignals, (__bridge void *)signal);

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I'm porting iOS 7.1 projects to iOS 8 that are using RAC. d I'm getting crashes in `RacDynamicSignal.m` on `CFSetRemoveValue(RACActiveSignals, (__bridge void *)signal);`

Any idea what might cause this?

```c
static void RACCheckActiveSignals(void) {
    // Clear this flag now, so another thread can re-dispatch to the main queue
    // as needed.
    OSAtomicAnd32Barrier(0, &RACWillCheckActiveSignals);

    RACSignalList * restrict elem;

    while ((elem = OSAtomicDequeue(&RACActiveSignalsToCheck, offsetof(RACSignalList, next))) != NULL) {
        RACDynamicSignal *signal = CFBridgingRelease(elem->retainedSignal);
        free(elem);

        if (signal.hasSubscribers) {
            // We want to keep the signal around until all its subscribers are done
            CFSetAddValue(RACActiveSignals, (__bridge void *)signal);
        } else {
            CFSetRemoveValue(RACActiveSignals, (__bridge void *)signal);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Agathe, the best place to discuss crashes is by creating an Issue on the RAC repo: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa. Thanks!

Comment: of course! i'm quite sure it's a threading issue so i'm not sure it's really something to do with RAC itself.

Comment: The RAC code above is intended to be thread safe. Even if it's not a problem with RAC, you'll have better luck chasing this down on the RAC repo.